# Erwiderung auf eine Entschuldigung?

Tags: phrase-request

> **This question also has an answer here (in English):**
>   [What should I reply for "Sorry" / "Entschuldigung"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25976/1224)

Gibt es, ähnlich wie es für „danke“ das Wort „bitte“ gibt (und umgekehrt), für Entschuldigungen eine Art „Standard“-Erwiderung? Mit „Standard“ meine ich hier, dass sie …

- das Thema, das die Entschuldigung hervorgerufen hat, gedanklich abschließt, aber trotzdem weitere Konversation (zu diesem oder einem anderen Thema) auf Wunsch erlaubt. Idealerweise hat eine solche Antwort daher keinen Bezug zum behandelten Thema. Die Antworten „ist [schon] okay“, „nix passiert“ oder „nicht so schlimm“ stellen in meinen Augen diesen Bezug – mehr oder weniger stark – her.
- möglichst neutral daherkommt, d. h. keine unnötigen Konnotationen der Überlegenheit oder Unterwürfigkeit besitzt. Aus diesem Grund fühlt sich die Antwort „akzeptiert“ für mich problematisch an.
- grammatikalisch korrekt ist und für sich Sinn ergibt. Hier fliegt dann die wahrscheinlich am häufigsten gelehrte (aber nicht mehr unbedingt genutzte) Antwort „bitte“ raus. Es sei denn, jemand kann mir den tieferen Sinn von „bitte“ als Antwort auf eine Entschuldigung erläutern.

Answer (score 8):

> Ist schon gut.

oder

> Ist schon in Ordnung.

sind zwei Möglichkeiten, ein "ich entschuldige mich" zu beantworten. Damit wird der Grund für die Entschuldigung abgeschwächt und das Thema als erledigt gekennzeichnet.

Übrigens:

Inhaltlich ist das "ich entschuldige mich" natürlich Unsinn, eigentlich kann man nur um Entschuldigung bitten. Die Schuld kann nur von jemand anderem genommen werden. Statt dem Bitten um Entschuldigung ist aber heute immer häufiger das "sich selber entschuldigen" anzutreffen. Das kann auch als Beschimpfung benutzt werden: "tschuldigun, mach mal endlich Platz!".

Comment: Ha, das erinnert mich an so ein Miststück, dass sich mit Ellbogen überall (sich die ganze Zeit entschuldigend) durchgedrängelt hat und als es nicht durchgelassen und beschimpft wurde immer sagte "ich hab mich doch entschuldigt". Sich selbst entschuldigen kann man natürlich nicht, trotzdem ist "sich [bei jemandem] entschuldigen" die richtige Formulierung, im Gegensatz zu "ich entschuldige mich", das nur sprachlich richtig ist, aber von vielen trotzdem wenigstens umgangssprachlich verwendet wird und in der Regel auch richtig gemeint ist.

Comment: "Sich entschuldigen" im Sinn von "um Entschuldigung bitten" steht schon in Grimms Wörterbuch drin. Das ist so ein komischer Internet-Mythos, dass das neu ("heute immer häufiger") und falsch/unhöflich wäre.

Answer (score 7):

Wie wärs mit „Keine Ursache!“? Das auslösende Thema wird damit auf neutrale Weise abgeschlossen, und die Antwort beinhaltet weder eine Über- noch eine Unterordnung. Vielmehr drückt der Antwortende aus, dass er sich nicht verletzt / beeinträchtigt / angegriffen fühlt. Grammatikalisch ist das als elliptische Ausdrucksweise („Dafür besteht / sehe ich **keine Ursache**!“) auch in Ordnung.

Comment: Klingt erstmal plausibel! "Keine Ursache" ist aber meines Wissens bei Entschuldigungen [noch] nicht gebräuchlich. Aber vielleicht können wir das ja ändern ;-)

Comment: Hmm - habe ich mir auch gerade überlegt... aber ich glaube, ich bin nicht ganz allein :-) - gerade mal gegoogelt: http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Bitte!%20Macht%20nichts!&bool=relevanz&suchspalte[]=erl_ou oder http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2216347 oder http://de.pons.eu/grammatik_englisch/kommunikation/soziale-konventionen/stabilisierung-von-kontakten/sich-entschuldigen-ndash-auf-entschuldigungen-reagieren/

Comment: Man könnte noch erwähnen, dass "Keine Ursache" vor allem eine gängige Antwort auf "Vielen Dank" ist.

Answer (score 6):

Formelle Variante (die ich selbst bisher nicht verwendet habe):

> "Ich bitte um Entschuldigung."
>   "Ich entspreche Ihrer Bitte."
>
> "Ich entschuldige mich." <sup><sub>(Die Problematik dieser Selbst-Entschuldigung wurde bereits in den anderen Antworten diskutiert)</sub></sup>
>   "Ich nehme Ihre Entschuldigung an."

Answer (score 6):

#### *Gerne*

Oft benutze ich auch *"Gerne!"* als Ausdruck, dass ich der Bitte um Entschuldigung gerne nachkomme.

> *"Entschuldigen Sie die Störung, können Sie mir bitte die genaue Uhrzeit sagen?" - "Gerne! Es ist jetzt viertel nach fünf."*
> *"Entschuldigung, dass ich mich verspätet habe" - "Gerne! Wollen wir gleich los?"*

#### *Macht nix*

Wenn es sich um ein Missgeschick gehandelt hatte, passt *"gerne"* natürlich nicht. Dann nehme ich neben den bereits erwähnten Varianten manchmal auch ein einfaches *"Macht nix"* (umgangssprachliche Kurzform für *"Das macht nichts aus"*).

> *"Ich bitte vielmals um Entschuldigung, dass ich mein Bier auf Ihrem Mantel verschüttet habe." - "Macht nichts."*

*"Macht nichts"* ist allerdings sehr knapp und impliziert nicht selten ein dazu gedachtes *"Macht **doch** was..."*.

#### Kein Kommentar

Bei manchen Bitten um Entschuldigung ziehe ich aber mit vielen meiner Mitdeutschen gleich und sage gar nichts (je nach Situation lächle ich vielleicht freundlich oder runzle die Stirn), z.B.:

> *"Entschuldigung, darf ich mal vorbei?"*
> *"Entschuldigung"* nach einer Rempelei.

Comment: Gerne passt zwar prima bei deinem ersten Beispiel, beim zweiten finde ich es aber etwas seltsam. Aber es wird sicher nicht missverstanden. Es ergibt natürlich irgendwo Sinn, jemandem zu sagen, dass man seine Entschuldigung *gerne* annimmt...

Answer (score 4):

Meines Erachtens ist die zweite Randbedingung in sich problematisch:

> - möglichst neutral daherkommt, d.h. keine unnötigen Konnotationen der Überlegenheit oder Unterwürfigkeit besitzt. Aus diesem Grund fühlt
>     sich die Antwort "akzeptiert" für mich problematisch an.

Die Überlegenheit dessen, der eine Entschuldigung gewährt/akzeptiert ergibt sich nämlich stringent aus der Situation, die der Entschuldigung bedarf.

Man entschuldigt sich ja für Formen der Grenzverletzungen, die als aggressiver Akt gedeutet werden können, aber nicht so gemeint waren. Deswegen begibt sich der, der unabsichtlich machtvoll auftrat in eine betont machtlose Position.

Demjenigen, der die Entschuldigung akzeptieren soll, mag das peinlich sein, so dass er die Unterwürfigkeit selbst ausschlägt ("keine Ursache"), was die Situation beendet - man kann aber auch die Rolle kurz akzeptieren, und die Entschuldigung annehmen ("akzeptiert", "ich nehme die Entschuldigung an"). Da die Annahme der Entschuldigung entlastend erlebt wird nimmt der, der sie erbat auch gerne an - das formelle Rollenspiel kann die Ernsthaftigkeit der Situation unterstreichen und Verbindlichkeit signalisieren.

Einen Schubser in der Menge wird man aber i.d.R. zurecht oberflächlich abhandeln, und tut nicht schlecht daran "keine Ursache" zu erwidern, auch wenn eine Ursache sehr wohl vorliegt.

Comment: Ähnliche Überlegungen habe ich nach dem Absenden meiner Antwort auch getroffen, aber Du triffst den Nagel auf den Kopf, so dass ich mir eigene Ausführungen in der Richtung sparen kann und Dir einfach +1 gebe. Kurzgefasst könnte man wohl sagen: Es gibt keine neutrale Erwiderung auf eine (Bitte zur) Entschuldigung, weil es keine neutralen Situationen gibt, die eine solche hervorrufen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube nicht, dass es hier eine einzige akzeptierte standard-Antwort gibt, also keinen formalisierten Austausch.

Erklärungsversuch für "bitte": Man kann sich nicht selbst ent-schuldigen, man kann nur darum bitten. Man bittet also um Entschuldigung, diese wird gewährt, man bedankt sich, der Dank wird mit einem "bitte" quittiert. Letzteres wird ja häufig sowieso zusammengezogen, indem man bereits bei Aushändigung "bitte" sagt und nicht erst auf ein "danke" wartet: "Ich bitte um Entschuldigung." - "Entschuldigung gewährt; bitteschön." So redet natürlich niemand (mehr?).

Comment: Ich würde mal schätzen, dass 50 % der Deutschen ohne Probleme "ich entschuldige mich sagen." und wenn du das nicht als Entschuldigung annimmst ist das dein Problem.

Comment: @bernd_k: ich verstehe nicht so recht, wie Dein Kommentar zur Antwort paßt...

Comment: Die Aussage man kann sich nicht selbst entschuldigen ist keine sprachliche Aussage, sondern eine moralische.

Comment: @user unknown ich beziehe mich auf fzwo Eklärungsversuch für "bitte": Man kann sich nicht selbst ent-schuldigen.

Comment: bernd_k: Natürlich wird im allgemeinen "ich entschuldige mich" oder "Entschuldigung" gesagt. Die Kritik daran war auch nicht der zentrale Punkt meiner Antwort, sondern eben Ansatz zur Erklärung des "bitte".

Answer (score 0):

Was man im Schriftlichen gut sagen kann, ist, dass man für das Verständnis dankt, welches einem der entgegenbringt, der um Verzeihung gebeten hat.

Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Community "such as working code or documentation citations." Wie bitte? Wie kommt denn so ein unsinniger Kommentar zustande, ist das ein Bot, der die erzeugt?