# What should I reply for "Sorry" / "Entschuldigung"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Erwiderung auf eine Entschuldigung?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3489)*

To make it more clear: I am not asking how I should apologize, but how to respond to an apology.

I have heard something similar to the following whenever I had to tell "Sorry":

> 1. Kein Problem.
> 2. Macht es. (Not sure if they really meant that)

Are there anything more that I could tell in response to an apology?

And really `Macht es` means you can do it?

Comment: _Macht nichts_, not _macht es_.

Comment: what does that mean? you don't have to be sorry? or you shouldn't do that?

Comment: You mean the German translation of *`You are welcome`* ?

Comment: but nobody tells you are welcome for sorry.. its for thank you.

Comment: But i would like to know that as well. Other than `Bitte schön` what else can I tel?

Comment: @ViniVasundharan Thanks for the clarification :-) *`Keine Ursache`* is a often used phrase for replying to *thank you*.

Comment: For sorry and Thank you the same word (`keine Ursache`) for responding? This language is full of oddity. :)

Comment: Every language is full of oddity! :-D But in US English, we might also easily respond to "Excuse me" or "Thank you" in the exact same way: "No problem", trying to convey that there is nothing that needed to be excused, or it was such a small effort involved that thanking isn't even necessary. (Although neither of these situations might literally be true. Someone could go to a great effort or you might have committed a grave offense, and the response still could be something along the lines of "it was nothing, forget about it".)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no canonic answer to *Entschuldigung* or *tut mir leid* rather unlike the canonic answer to *danke* (which is *bitte*). Rather, there is a multitude of expressions one can and will use none being inherently preferred.

- Kein Problem.
- Keine Ursache.
- Passt schon.
- Nichts passiert.
- Alles in Ordnung/OK.
- Mach dir nichts draus.
- Macht nichts.
- and many more.

However, if the *Entschuldigung* is of the more formal type, i.e. you’re trying to clear up an argument you had with someone, it is also common to answer along the lines of *apology accepted,* e.g.

> Entschuldigung angenommen.

Note that it would sound weird if someone ran into you on a bus and you answered that to their *sorry,* so save that one for the *real* apologies.

Comment: Is there any particular situation where i should be using these? or could it be used in any situation when I am hearing a sorry .(Except _Entschuldigung angenommen_)

Comment: *Kein Problem* kind of assumes a problem (but not really). Other than that you could use practically every one in practically every situation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Would you mind listing the words that could be used as response to thanks as well? So that i dont have to post another question. if there is nothing other than bitte, you don't have to edit your answer.

Comment: *Passt schon* is more for the Bavarian speech: *Passtscho*. Besides that, *Halb so wild* could get on the list.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Jan's answer, you can say "Schon OK". It has a very subtle annoyed sub-tone and you might follow it up with some kind of request for them to refrain from doing so in the future.

Example: In the office, someone used your personal mug. That person realizes it and apologizes to you. You could answer: "Schon ok, *but in the future, please don't use someone's personal mug*".

"Passt schon" is similar in usage.

Answer (score 2):

- Kein Problem.
- Macht nichts.
- Keine Ursache.
- Alles OK.
- Nichts passiert.
- Alles in Ordnung.
- etc. pp.

Was halt geeignet ist, um auszudrücken, dass es nicht weiter schlimm ist. Es gibt keine "Standardantwort".

---

Translation: Or anything else that can be used to express that it is no problem. There is no "standard reply".

Comment: pp. ? What is that?

Comment: *`pp`*  means *`perge, perge`* see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera

Comment: It would be great if you could comment in english. I cant understand these long german sentences. And when I google translate. i will understand it wrong. :(

Comment: @ViniVasundharan Tried to translate.

Comment: Yes.  @heinrich5991.  I did the translate.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan No, I mean I tried to translate the post. But the edit isn't visible yet.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan Sorry, should have answered in English.

Comment: @Veredomon : Yes of course. Sorry should be answered in English :)