# Mein Chef: Entschuldige, dass ich dir erst jetzt antworte, wie kann ich antworten?

Tags: letter

Ich habe eine E-Mail an meinen vorherigen Chef gesendet, Er antwortete mir spät und fing an, diesen Satz zu beantworten:

**Entschuldige, dass ich dir erst jetzt antworte**.

Deshalb schäme ich mich und weiss nicht, wie ich darauf reagieren und antworten kann.

Ich würde mich über Ihre Hilfe freuen.

Comment: Warum schämst du dich, wenn dein Chef spät antwortet? Da kannst du ja nichts dafür.

Comment: Ich bin jünger als er, ich denke, er sollte sich nicht bei mir entschuldigen

Comment: Deutsches [Duplikat](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3489/1696).

Comment: @HusamEbish: Es ist höflich, sich in diesem Fall zu entschuldigen. Warum erwartest du von deinem Chef, dass er unhöflich zu dir ist? Sei froh, dass er einen Fehler eingestehen kann.

Comment: @guidot Thanks for the suggestion, I've seen the answers, they meet the purpose among friends, are they suitable to answer them at my boss?

Comment: @ Hubert Schölnast, das ist klar, aber wie kann ich ihn höflich Antworten? Zumal ich nicht sehr gut deutsch kann

Comment: Am besten ist es, gar nicht auf diese Bemerkung einzugehen. Du erreichst damit nur, dass dein Chef sich erneut mit seinem Versäumnis beschäftigen muss, anstatt mit der Sache. Das wäre sehr unhöflich.

Comment: @HusamEbish _"Ich bin jünger als er, ich denke, er sollte sich nicht bei mir entschuldigen"_ Das ist Unsinn (Schweiz oder nicht).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "Unsinn" würde ich das nicht nennen, aber einen deutlichen "kulturellen Unterschied" :)

Comment: @Arsak _"aber einen deutlichen "kulturellen Unterschied""_ von der Schweizerischen oder der (vermutlich arabischen) Kultur des Fragestellers? Und selbst wenn, der Ex-Boss enschuldigt sich, dass ist doch kein Grund sich zu schämen?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Zwischen der (ursprünglichen) Kultur des Fragestellers und der Kultur seines Chefs bzw der hier antwortenden/kommentierenden Usern

Comment: @Arsak May be we should have a SE site to ask about specific cultural interactions. I am not very eager to put an Area51 request into that, Though that might be a helpful place to discuss questions regarding cultural misconceptions and how to respect specific cultural concerns.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ InterpersonalSkills.SE might cover this, I'm not sure though

Comment: @Arsak ATM there's no site I can see covering that AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je nachdem, wie kumpelhaft das Verhältnis ist (er redet Dich ja offenbar mit Du an), könntest Du sowas wie *macht nichts* oder *kein Problem* antworten - oder seine diesbezügliche Bemerkung ganz ignorieren.

Comment: Vielen Dank, aber ist das höflich in Swiss kulture?